# Transferring Sqlite DB file using libcurl functions but unable to open db file immediately to send the data to database

Tags: c++, sqlite, ftp, libcurl

I am running a C++ application which communicates with a PLC based machine.

PLC based machine creates a .db(SQLITE) file once the machine processes the parts.

I wrote a function to transfer the sqlite db from PLC machine to PC using libcurl functions.

After the transfer is complete, i need to loop through the db file and transfer the data to the company network database table.

I have an issue with looping through the file once the transfer is done.

The file when reading throws an exception "(11) SQLITE_CORRUPT" - "Disk Image is Malformed".

But once i close my c++ application and open again, the last sqlite db file is able to open and loop through.

**I am attaching the code below, let me know if there is a way to make the db file available to read once transferred through libcurl library. Should i be using some extra commands to make it available.**

[Information of the ftp server.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brDfA.png)

```
char dbfile[128];
char ofile[512];

//Pulling all the information about the ftp server information from parsed.xml -> Request/DataBlock/LogFile/Host, Path, File

char *host = tagTextValue(doc, "REQUEST.DATABLOCK.LOGFILE.HOST");// -- 172.16.1.100
if (host) 
{
    if (char *path = tagTextValue(doc, "REQUEST.DATABLOCK.LOGFILE.PATH")) // -- /pub/export/mdt
    {
        if (char *file= tagTextValue(doc, "REQUEST.DATABLOCK.LOGFILE.FILE"))// --  20200226_004636_90180.db
        {
            sprintf_s( dbfile, sizeof(dbfile), "ftp://%s/%s/%s", host, path, file );//Host Address  
            sprintf_s(ofile, sizeof(ofile), "c:\\xxxxx\\xxxxx\\%s", file);//Destination Address
        }
    }
}

///////////Start of FTP///////////////////
struct FtpFile 
{
  const char *filename;
  FILE *stream;
};

FtpFile ftp = 
{
    ofile, /* name to store the file as if successful */ 
    NULL
};



CURL *url = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(url,  CURLOPT_URL, dbfile);// dbfile has the complete path where to pull the file from.

FILE *ffp = fopen(ofile, "w"); // ofile mentions the destination on the receiving end

curl_easy_setopt(url, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, my_fwrite);
curl_easy_setopt(url, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &ftp);
curl_easy_setopt(url, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "ftpuser:xxxx");// Passing the login details to FTP server to pull the information from the 'server/machine'

CURLcode  res = curl_easy_perform(url);

fclose(ffp);
curl_easy_cleanup(url);

////////////////End of FTP/////////////////////////

sqlite3 *db;

sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

char sql[1024];

Sleep(20000);

WireBondDataUploadType      rec = rec2;         
const char* sql1 = "select xxxxxxxxxx";
bool storeSuccessful = false;

const char *ofile2 = "c:\\xxxxx\\xxxxxxx\\20200310_021605_20039.db";
int rc;
rc = sqlite3_open(ofile, &db);  //ST Opening a new Database connection

if (rc == SQLITE_OK)
{
    rc=sqlite3_prepare(db, sql1, -1, &stmt, NULL);
    if(rc != 0)
    {
        sqlite3_close(db);
    } 
    else if(rc == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
      //Process the information by reading the db file.
      xxxxxxxx
      xxxxxxxx
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem was we forgot to the close the "opened" ftp file(ofile) in the above mentioned code.

Reference link - [https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpget.html][1]